# gb4e tabbing problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics, gb4e

I am using `gb4e` to align examples. But when elements within `[]` are complex, sentences cannot be aligned. For example, in the picture attached, two 'which' are not aligned.  How can I align sentences in this case?

```
\begin{exe}  

\ex \begin{xlist}  

\ex[??/*]  {Which ~~~}

\ex[*]  {Which ~~}

\end{xlist}

\end{exe}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `\ex[\phantom{??/}*] ...` for the second "Which"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the missing content using `\phantom`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
  \ex
  \begin{xlist}
    \ex[??/*]           {Which \ldots}
    \ex[\phantom{??/}*] {Which \ldots}
    \ex[*]              {Which \ldots}
  \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```